# Which questions are considered toward the percentage of questions answered for a site?

Tags: support

I want to know which questions are considered or ignored when calculating the [percent of questions answered for a site](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#percentanswered).

Considering the following situations for instance:

- A question with an accepted answer
- A question with an answer, but not accepted
- A question marked as a duplicate

Which of these count toward the answered % (or unanswered %)? Which don't?

Answer (score 2):

Take [Expatriates.SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).

The site you link says 96% of questions are answered.

There are [379 non-closed questions](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3A0). There are [357 answered questions](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3A0+answers%3A1). 357/379 = 94.2%

If we remove the switch for closed, we get [423 questions](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion) and [384 answered questions](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1) for a percentage of 90.8%

If we only look at *accepted* answers to non-closed questions then we get the same 379 questions, and only [176 answered questions](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+closed%3A0+hasaccepted%3A1) which is 46.4% answered.

So I think it's clear that the conditions are something like:

```
Non-closed questions with > 0 answers
-------------------------------------
        Non-closed questions
```

The difference between the 96% shown on the site list and the 94% through advanced search could be caused by (pick 2, they're small):

1. Caching
2. Unicorns
3. Deleted Answers
4. Deleted Questions
5. Y2k bug
6. One of the Tim's
7. All of the above

Comment: Doesn't it take upvoted answers into account too? So you could have a question with 1 upvoted answer compared to a question with 10 un-voted answers and the latter would be included in the 'unanswered' criteria while the former is 'answered'.

Comment: @JonW, that would lower the stats (which are already below the published ones) so I don't think so. Perhaps there's a more authoritative source out there, but I invite you to check at any rate. Perhaps only upvoted questions?

Comment: I think if A = no. of question displayed at site.SE.com/questions B = no. of questions with no upvoted or accepted answers displayed at site.SE.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest, then percent answered = (A-B)/A*100 right?

Comment: @Pandya Actually, JonW is right -- answered means the % of questions with upvoted answers -- questions for which an answer has been vetted by the community.